# PHP GD - imagerotate for a jpeg image is not working

Tags: php, image-rotation, php-gd

Title says JPEG. But I tried PNG. It didn't work.
GD supports imagerotate function.

```
 if (function_exists('imagerotate')) { 
     echo "test";
 }
```

It outputs the word test. So i assume I have imagerotate function.

```
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($width + 10, $height + 10);
...
```

I did some image porcess. I can see the processed image without any problem. But i want to rotate the final image. So i did the following.

```
 imagerotate($im,180,0);
 imagepng($im,$png,9);
 imagedestroy($im);
```

But I am still getting the image without rotation.
I even just tried to rotate a image without doing any process. It didn't work too.

Comment: $png has some name. I am trying it with the following name Output.png

Comment: And you are 100% sure the file is being written? You compared the file's "last modified" time and it's storing an unrotated image?

Comment: Yes. I checked with different names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign the rotated image to another variable before create the png.

```
$rotatedImage = imagerotate($im,180,0);
 imagepng($rotatedImage,$png,9);
 imagedestroy($rotatedImage);
```